# Java EE's @PostConstruct can only be static on "the application client". What does this term mean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

The documentation for [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) includes the following language:

> The method MUST NOT be static except for the application client.

What is meant by "the application client" in this context (and is this term documented somewhere)?  By extension, when may a `@PostConstruct`-annotated method be static, and when must it be non-static?

Comment: Is it linked to the [Enterprise Application Client](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html) ? In such module, can some classes represent the application itself? If yes, they can have a  `public static void main()`-like method, can't they. Then maybe it's a parallel _constructor -> postconstruct_ and _main -> postconstruct_. I never use Application Client before so these are pure assumptions but I'm interested in the answer for my personal knowledge

Comment: An enterprise application client is a swing based application, in which remote ejb injection can take place.